# Return type of JOINing stored procedure - PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, composite-types

Is it possible to express return type of stored procedure that returns joined tables using table type of one of joined tables?

My stored procedure looks like this:

```
CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION selectJoin()
RETURNS SETOF ???
AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY SELECT t1.*, t2.name
                 FROM t1, t2
                 WHERE t1.t2_id = t2.id;
END; $$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Table `t1` has many (approx 70) columns so I'd like to somehow reuse the `t1` type in RETURNS clause. Something like `(t1, varchar(30))` or composite type inheritace. Is is possible?

PostgreSQL version 9.3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, I am afraid that's **not possible**. I have been wishing this was possible myself on several occasions. Either you have a registered row (composite) type that matches the return type or you have to list columns individually.

```
CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION select_join()
  RETURNS TABLE (col1 int, col2 date, ...) AS ...
```

There is a somewhat awkward **workaround** with returning a nested composite type, but it's not exactly the same. See:

- [Easy way to have return type be SETOF table plus additional fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17825717/939860)

**Or** you [create a composite type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createtype.html):

```
CREATE TYPE foo AS (col1 int, col2 date, ...);

CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION select_join()
  RETURNS SETOF foo AS ...
```

A [`VIEW`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createview.html) also registers its row type automatically. For the simple test case you present, you might just use a view *instead* of the function to begin with (like @a_horse commented):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW my_view AS 
SELECT t1.*, t2.name
FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON t1.t2_id = t2.id;
```

Or you create the view for the purpose of registering the row type conveniently. You might add `LIMIT 0` to document that the view is not meant to return rows, but that's optional.

```
CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION select_join()
  RETURNS SETOF my_view AS ...
```

Be aware that this introduces a dependency (like with any other view) and Postgres will prevent dropping the table and some other manipulations, unless you drop depending views first.

Comment: Is this  still not possible in the recents versions ? thanks

Comment: @yasseros: Still not possible in Postgres 13. I added a link to a possible workaround above.